# How do I mask a subdirectory URL without a trailing slash using htaccess and not have the internal query string appended?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Arg! So, I have a URL like this:

```
mysite.com/foo-bar
```

or

```
mysite.com/foo-bar/
```

When the user requests this address, I don't want it to change, but internally (invisibly) I want this to actually be the address:

```
main.php?page=foo-bar
```

For years, I have used this htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\/{0,1}$ main.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

And it worked fine. But now, when I **(1)** try it with a sub-directory:

```
RewriteRule ^sub\/([a-z0-9\-]+)\/{0,1}$ main.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

And **(2)** don't add a trailing slash, it suddenly appends the "internal" query string.

So, this:

```
mysite.com/sub/foo-bar/
```

Works fine. But this:

```
mysite.com/sub/foo-bar
```

Still works internally, but the URL redirects to this:

```
mysite.com/sub/foo-bar/?page=foo-bar
```

I tried removing [QSA], but that doesn't make a difference. Besides, I need it, because I want any extra vars the user passes to be added to mine. For example:

```
mysite.com/sub/foo-bar?uservar=42
```

Should not change to the viewer, but internally should be:

```
main.php?page=foo-bar&uservar=42
```

I have been at this for hours reading Apache docs and StackOverflow posts with similar problems, but none of the solutions work. If I don't put a trailing slash in the subdirectory requests, the slash gets added and internal vars get shown to the viewer. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening due to `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash to your URI which is for a real directory. To fix you can use:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^sub/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ main.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: "DirectorySlash Off" seems to have fixed it. It's weird that it would add the query string when it thinks it has to add the dir slash, but htaccess is a... mysterious lady. I didn't want a trailing slash if the user doesn't request it, so I didn't add the second part. Thanks!